# How to save a .txt file from a virtual server to my real machine?

Tags: linux, save, debian

My problem is: My Debian9 which is run on a virtual box is not working just wihtout internet mode. CTRL+C - CTRL+V commend is not working, i don't know why.
How can I save my txt file to my real PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you want transferring files from a **Linux VM** to your local machine. I recommend take read [this post](https://support.cloudandheat.com/en/getting_started/CloudCompute/Transferring_files_to_and_from_a_Linux_VM.html), it explain how to do this in Linux, Mac and Windows.